# create attributes of buttons dynamically depending on div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a big problem which is driving me crazy:
i have a scrolling page with lots of divs and each has a different id, one below the other and no gap between them. 
at the bottom of the viewport are 4 fixed buttons which all have a click function:

```
 $("#button1").click(function() { 
    $('#firstdiv').css("background-image", "url(bg1.jpg)");

 $("#button2").click(function() { 
    $('#firstdiv').css("background-image", "url(bg2.jpg)");

 $("#button3").click(function() { 
    $('#firstdiv').css("background-image", "url(bg3.jpg)");

 $("#button4").click(function() { 
    $('#firstdiv').css("background-image", "url(bg4.jpg)");
```

as you can see the buttons are for changing the background image of the current div.

when im scrolling down and the next div comes in it, fires an event. in this event i want to change the function of each button with different attributes for example

```
  $("#button1_2").click(function() { 
    $('#seconddiv').css("background-image", "url(bg5.jpg)");
```

and so on..

the function is the same, but it works for the second div and another bg-images...
could someone please give me an approach to do this dynamically that i dont have to make like 25 click functions for all the divs?

Comment: So you want to have the buttons give their associated divs a different background image depending on the scroll position?

Comment: right! i can trigger the scroll position with inview.js! this works very well... but the rest ive got some problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your buttons so that they look something like this (the attributes are the important things):

```
<button class="image-button" data-image="bg1.jpg">Text</button>
```

And then you could apply your event handler to all of them at once:

```
$(".image-button").click(function() { 
    var url = 'url(' + $(this).data('image') + ')';

    $('#firstdiv').css('background-image', url);
});
```

Comment: okay this works so far, thank you for that! but i have to create all buttons i need. i mean there are always 4 buttons visible, but for every div a have to append new buttons with a different data-image right?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```
<span class="btn" data-num="1">button1</span>
<span class="btn" data-num="2">button2</span>
```

jquery :

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $('#firstdiv').css("background-image", "url(bg"+$(this).attr("data-num")+".jpg)");
})
```